# Clearly structuring testable, modular code with burgeoning business requirement conditionals

Tags: php, design-patterns, slim, command-pattern, chain-of-responsibility

I'm trying to conceptualize the clearest way to write code for something like a Yelp or FB check-in type system, but
with a check-out component, too. I'm using PHP.

The basic requirement might be:
 Check in:
  if it is type 'building', I need to

1. look up the actual building by it's UUID to get it's primary key, which we will log with the check-in to later pull them in to reports
   (checked in to building '123 Main Street').
2. they can't be currently already checked into to anything
3. they have to be within X meters of the premises
4. if they are not withing X meters of the premises, there must be an exception string to log to explain why.

if it is type 'room', I need to

1. look up the actual room by it's UUID to get it's primary key, which
   we will log with the check-in to later pull them in to reports
   (checked in to '123 Main Street -> Room 212').
2. they need to be checked into a building already
3. they can't be checked into a room already

There is a 'check-out' phase too, which I mention so you can understand that it's not truly like Yelp where you just say
"I was here". It's not a single action to just check-in; it will be followed by a 'check-out', which I won't cover here
for brevity. My question is about creating cleaner controllers, methods and design patterns for structuring code that
satisfies the above.

So, the request sends json, hits the (Slim) app, goes to a controller for the method (in this case, Post).  We have
their GPS coordinates, the UUID of the building/room they are checking into, their ID (via authentication), and the type
of check-in, building or room. Something like:

```
{
    "latitude": "33.333", // these only matter if it is 'building'
    "longitude": "-80.343", // these only matter if it is 'building'
    "buildingUuid": "ff97f741-dba2-415a-a9e0-5a64633e13ad", // could also be 'roomUuid' ...
    "type": "building", // or 'room'
    "exceptionReason": null
}
```

I have all the ability to check their relationship to the building coordinates, look up the building ID, etc. I'm
looking for ideas on how to make this code straightforward, maintainable and testable. For one, you can see how my
switch statements (far code block) have gotten way out of hand, but I don't know how else to structure this. *That's the
crux of the question*.

Without any requirements: (feaux code)

```
switch($type) {
    case 'building':
        $model = new \Namespace\Models\Building($this->container);
        break;

    case 'room':
        $model = new \Namespace\Models\Room($this->container);
        break;

    default:
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Type {$type} not understood");
}

$model->checkIn(); // polymorphic method that all 'type' classes will have, based on an interface implemented
```

I'm trying to avoid switch statements but at some point I have to use something to figure out *what* to instantiate,
right?  Polymorphism doesn't help me here, as I understand it does for a lot of switch statements, because I don't yet
have an object.

So, that seems pretty straightforward, to me. What isn't clear is when I want to add some of the requirements. What is
the proper way to handle this type of structure (which only involves TWO types... this could get out of hand in a
hurry).

(feaux code)

```
switch ($type) {
    case 'building':
        $model = new \Namespace\Models\CheckInBuilding($this->container);
        $alreadyInTest = new \Namespace\Models\Buildings\BuildingTestIn($this->container);
        $building = new \Namespace\Models\Buildings\Building($this->getData('buildingUuid'), $this->container);

        if (!$building) {
            throw new Exceptions\FailBadInput('Building not found: ' . $this->getData('buildingUuid'));
        }

        $model->setBuilding($building); // building object used for these properties: ID, coordinates for the lat/long 'nearby' check
        break;

    case 'room':
        $model = new \Namespace\Models\CheckInRoom($this->container);
        $alreadyInTest = new \Namespace\Models\Rooms\RoomTestIn($this->container);
        $room = new \Namespace\Models\Rooms\Room($this->getData('roomUuid'), $this->container);

        if (!$room) {
            throw new Exceptions\FailBadInput('Room not found: ' . $this->getData('roomUuid'));
        }

        $model->setRoom($room); // room object used for these properties: ID
        break;

    default:
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Type {$type} not understood");
}

$model->setAlreadyInTest($alreadyInTest);
$model->setData($this->getData());
$model->checkIn();
//
// Now, for 'building|room', this has all the data internal to check:
//   - if they are nearby (but only if in building)
//   - to test if they are already logged in
//   - to log the primary key ID with the request
//

//
// In addition, and not covered here, if they are not in range of the building, they can still check-in, but need to
// type a short reason why they are doing a check-in and not in nearby range ('GPS broken, etc', who knows...). So,
// would I add yet another class, instantiated here so it can be mocked in a test, and passed in empty, so it could
// eventually be used to insert an exception reason (in a different table than the check-in table)?
//
```

Based on design patterns, if I need to add another `$type`, I just do it here, which seems like is fairly good. But...
this is in a controller... it's abusing the switch statment... and it seems brittle/fragile because of all the different
things that are instantiated and passed in.

I have a DIC, but I don't know that it makes things any clearer.

While it would clear up the code here, I don't want to instantiate any classes in the actual models (like, I don't want
to create the 'alreadyInTester' object inside an object) because I want this to be testable and doing that seems like
would make it much more difficult to test/mock.

Having said that, the tests have the same problem. There is so much riding on these various requirements and how to test
them, that the tests are not very isolated. I can mock the alreadyInTest and building/room objects to isolate the
checkIn method, and test building/room individually, but to test them all together, like in an integration test, now I
risk non-determininstic tests because I find this to be a messy approach.

My last thought would be something like this, but I worry about fattening the controller too much: (feaux code)

```
switch($type) {
    case 'building':
        $alreadyInTest = new \Namespace\Models\Buildings\BuildingTestIn($this->container);
        if($alreadyInTest->isIn()) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('You are already checked in to a building');
        }

        $building = new \Namespace\Models\Buildings\Building($this->getData('buildingUuid'), $this->container);

        if (!$building) {
            throw new Exceptions\FailBadInput('Building not found: ' . $this->getData('buildingUuid'));
        }

        $model = new \Namespace\Models\Building($this->container);
        break;

    case 'room':
        $alreadyInTest = new \Namespace\Models\Rooms\RoomTestIn($this->container);

        if($alreadyInTest->isIn()) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('You are already checked in to a room');
        }

        $room = new \Namespace\Models\Rooms\Room($this->getData('roomUuid'), $this->container);

        if (!$room) {
            throw new Exceptions\FailBadInput('Room not found: ' . $this->getData('roomUuid'));
        }

        $model = new \Namespace\Models\Room($this->container);
        break;

    default:
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Type {$type} not understood");
}

$model->setData($this->getData());
$model->checkIn();
```

Again, I feel like I should be abstracting those two if/throws (per case) elsewhere, but that doesn't seem to make this
any more straightforward (also: I admit this isn't a complicated example... yet), and the controller isn't any skinnier
in either example. I feel this last example is more clear, to me. The crux, to me, is that each time something would be
added, it would mean adding more to the switch statement. I would think a polymorphic system would be better, but since
there would be outside classes needed to do the requirement checking, that I'd have to instantiate and pass a ton of
objects in anyway, making it just as complex. Instantiating classes inside each check-in object is not as testable. I
was thinking maybe Chain of Responsibility or Command patterns might be useful, but don't seem to be quite a true fit.

I go round and round.

So, is one of these the best way, or is there something I could be doing better?

Comment: If you start thinking about a checkIn as an object, you can use the Strategy pattern to represent each different type of checkIn. Then you can use a Factory can return the proper checkIn object for a given type.

Comment: I've thought about Template and Strategy, but I feel like there are those several other classes that need to be fed in through the constructor or a setter that complicate things; in addition, I've strongly considered the Factory in order to build the object in one place; but then all I'm doing is moving that switch statement there (admittedly, it could only ever need to be in that place, though).

Comment: What I've been considering since I wrote this up is DIC based on this: https://www.sitepoint.com/dependency-injection-with-pimple/ which helped me understand using DI in a case were there was more than one level of instantiation.  I use pimple but in a much more simplified way (only ever returning a 'new' statement, not building up one like a factory would).  I might be aiming for high but I've struggled with this type of structure before; wanting to pass in an object that would be used to check something (like 'alreadyCheckedIn').  I appreciate your comment to help me solidify my thinking

Comment: DI is definitely a way to help with the instantiation and keep things clean and testable.